# What do the intermediate steps for this look like?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sort of confused about what steps happen in between the following to equations. I guess that Euler's formula is used in some way, but I'm not entirely clear about how.

Could someone explain to me what the intermediate steps look like?

$$
{1 - e^{-jw6} \over 1 - e^{-jw}} = {\sin(3w) \over \sin({w \over 2})} e^{-j5w/2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

From euler's formula $e^{i\omega} = \cos\omega + i\sin\omega$, it follows that $$
  e^{i\omega} - e^{-i\omega} = i2\sin \omega \text{.}
$$
To bring $1 - e^{-i2\omega}$ into the required form, you factor out the term $e^{-i\omega}$, i.e. do  $$
  1 - e^{-i2\omega} = \left(e^{i\omega} - e^{-i\omega}\right)e^{-i\omega} = i2e^{-i\omega}\sin\omega \text{.}
$$

Doing that for both the nominator and the denominator yields the desired result.